# vagrant up Freezing

Tags: freeze, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I have vagrant installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 computer. And I have added the Laravel/Homestead box. It worked great for a long time. But suddenly when I run the 'vagrant up' command, it proceed all the way to the 'Booting VM' step and whole machine is getting stuck. (I cannot even turn on the caps-lock button). To continue I should force power-off the computer. I ran the 'vagrant box update' and it updated the box but problem is still same. I checked the Vagrantfile using 'vagrant validate' and it says 'Vagrantfile validated successfully.'

What should I do to get rid of this problem. pls help!

Comment: I have found that, this problem can be solved by upgrading the VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a number of times in the past as well. I know this isn't a helpful answer but I've had to move the "Vagrantfile" file to another directory and start all over. If you loose work inside the VM this is not helpful, but if you just need the functionality this might help.

I haven't tried using `vagrant destroy` but it's essentially the same. You'll lose your work.

Also this might help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/994926/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-on-vagrant-up